# Printing Rectangle Star Pattern but based on coordinate

Tags: python

I am learning python but I am trying to make star Rectangle but based on coordinate.

```
rows = 5
cols = 5

for i in range(0, rows):
    for j in range(0, cols):
        print("*", end=" ")
    print()
```

Output:

```
* * * * *
* * * * *
* * * * *
* * * * *
* * * * *
```

I want to print like this:

```
* * * * *
* *     *
*   *   *
*     * *
* * * * *
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following program should help:

```
rows = 5
cols = 5

for i in range(0, rows):
    for j in range(0, cols):
        if i==0 or i==rows-1 or j ==0 or j ==cols-1 or j == i:
            print("*", end=" ")
        else:
            print(" ", end=" ")
    print()
```

Explaination:
There are 3 conditions where `*` should be printed:

1. The row is the first or the last: Checked as `i==0 or i==rows-1`
2. The column is the first or the last: Checked as:`j ==0 or j ==cols-1`
3. The `row number == column number` or `i==j`.